# Get Attributes of HTML 5 Circles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have multiple html circles that are appended to an `svg` using D3.js.  Each circle doesn't have any ID or Class and looks like when I inspect the elements in the browser:

```
<circle cx="50" cy="80" r="1" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></circle>
```

I want to get the values of `cx` and `cy` into javascript variables.

I tried something like:

```
var v = $('circle').value;
```

but how do I reference the attributes `cx` and `cy`?

I tried `var x_val = $('circle.cx').value;` but that is undefined.

Also tried `var x_val = $('circle').data('cx');` but that is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.value;` gets the value of a plain JavaScript object, not a jquery object.

`$('circle').data('cx')`; gets the value of the attribute `data-cx=""` or a value setted previously with the method `$('circle').data('cx', 'whatever');`

To fetch the `cx` and `cy` values, use :

```
var x_val = $('circle').attr('cx');
var y_val = $('circle').attr('cy');
```

UPDATE:

to iterate into multiple circles :

```
var x_val, y_val;
$circleArray = $('circle'); //get all circles

$circleArray.each(function(idx, el){//go through each circle

  x_val = $(el).attr('cx');//get cx
  y_val = $(el).attr('cy');//get cy

  $('#result').append(idx+': '+x_val+' / '+y_val);//here: print the values, but replace this with whatever you need
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/pu2cnLgk/1/**

Comment: Thanks. Although I am getting 'undefined' when I try that.  I have multiple circles and none of them have an ID or Class. Is that why I am getting 'undefined'? How should I iterate over them?

Comment: no the lack of Id or Class is not a problem. You can get this value without id and class because the $('circle') will fetch all element 'circle' in the page. Use the class or id if you want to precise which circle you want to fetch. I updated my answer to suit your post edit. the method .attr() is working well, take a look a the fiddle.

Comment: I should mention that the circles where added using D3.js.  I tried your solution, but I am not getting anything in .each(), console.log() doesn't even print anything.  When I print the circleArray, I see [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "circle", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function… ]

Comment: Yes D3 is good to mention... So if you have D3 you surely inserted your circle with javascript. So why don't you reuse the javascript variable of the circle created in javascript ? if it's not possible, this method (see `d3.js` doc) `d3.select("circle").attr("cx")` should help you (this is for one. Use a loop for all. Mix with my example above.).

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done without using JQuery, especially if your circle has an id.

```
<circle id='awesomeCircle' cx="50" cy="80" r="1" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></circle>
```

And your JavaScript code is:

```
var x = document.getElementById('awesomeCircle').getAttribute('cx');
var y = document.getElementById('awesomeCircle').getAttribute('cy');
```

If you're not willing to assign an id to the element, you can use

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('circle')[0].getAttribute('cx');
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('awesomeCircle')[0].getAttribute('cy');
```

This will affect and browser compatibility negatively though.

Answer (score 0):

$('circle') will give you jQuery Object. Hence

```
 $('circle').value  //undefined
```

as there is no value variable or method in jQuery.

As there are many circles you can do like this

```js
$('circle').each(function(index,elem){
  
   alert("cx :"+elem.getAttribute("cx")+"...cy :"+elem.getAttribute("cy")); //using JavaScript

   console.log("cx :"+$(elem).attr("cx")+"...cy :"+$(elem).attr("cy")); // using jQuery

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<circle cy="10" cx="210"></circle>
<circle cy="30" cx="210"></circle>
<circle cy="20" cx="201"></circle>
<circle cy="10" cx="210"></circle>
```